# When is backward search better than forward?

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, graph-algorithm

I'm studying graph search algorithms (for this question sake, lets limit algorithms only on DFS, BreadthFS, ID).

All these algorithms can be implemented as either forward search (from start node to end node) or backward search (from end node to start node).

My question is, when will backward search perform better than forward? Is there a general rule for that?

Comment: In general you can't predict what the difference will be, so just pick one and go with it.

Comment: If I have a simple graph (tree) with 4 nodes: a start node with 3 successors, where rightmost successor is an end node, then all three algorithms (DFS, BFS, ID) will perform better backward than forward. Correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a breadth-first search or iterative deepening, I think the mathematical answer to your question involves the notion of a "ball" around a vertex.  Define Ball(v, n) to be the set of nodes at distance at most n from node v, and let the distance from the start node s to the destination node t be d.  Then in the worst case a forward search will perform better than a backward search if |Ball(s, d)| < |Ball(t, d)|.  This is true because breadth-first search always (and ID in the worst case) expands out all nodes of some distance k from the start node before ever visiting any nodes of depth k + 1.  Consequently, if there's a smaller number of nodes around the start than the target a forward search should be faster, whereas if there's a smaller number of nodes around the target than the start and backward search should be faster.  Unfortunately, it's hard to know this number a priori; you usually either have to run the search to determine which is the case.  You could potentially use the [branching factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_factor) around the two nodes as a heuristic for this value, but it wouldn't necessarily guarantee one search would be faster.

One interesting algorithm you might want to consider exploring is [bidirectional breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search), which does a search simultaneously from the source and target nodes.  It tends to be much faster than the standard breadth-first search (in particular, with a branching factor b and distance d between the nodes, BFS takes roughly O(b<sup>d</sup>) time while bidirectional BFS takes O(b<sup>d/2</sup>)).  It's also not that hard to code up once you have a good BFS implementation.

As for depth-first search, I actually don't know of a good way to determine which will be faster because in the worst-case both searches could explore the entire graph before finding a path.  If someone has a good explanation about how to determine which will be better, it would be great if they could post it.